# Is my JSON file being formatted properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, electron

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "password-generator",
  "productName": "Password Generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Password generator desktop app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
    "build-installer": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "password-generator",
  },
  "win": {
    "target": ["nsis"],
    "icon": "/icon.png",
  },
  "nsis": {
    "installerIcon": "/icon.png",
    "uninstallerIcon": "/icon.png",
    "uninstallDisplayName": "Password Generator",
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
  },
  "author": "JipBit",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^22.7.0",
  },
}
```

**Error:**

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\Users\mel\Desktop\Password Generator\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 212 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "password-generator",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "pro'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

**Information:** When attempting to run npm start and npm run build-installer, I get this error about my package.json file. I got this error after adding on to my package.json while setting up to run the build-installer to make my electron app an executable.

**Edit of new error:**

```
'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! password-generator@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the password-generator@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially looking at it, you need a ',' on line 8 after:

```
"start": "electron ."
```

EDIT:

Try this, there are just a few misplaced commas:

```
{
    "name": "password-generator",
    "productName": "Password Generator",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Password generator desktop app",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "build-installer": "electron-builder"
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "password-generator"
    },
    "win": {
        "target": ["nsis"],
        "icon": "/icon.png"
    },
    "nsis": {
        "installerIcon": "/icon.png",
        "uninstallerIcon": "/icon.png",
        "uninstallDisplayName": "Password Generator",
        "oneClick": false,
        "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    },
    "author": "JipBit",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron-forge": "^5.2.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "electron-builder": "^22.7.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error saying: 'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I'm sure what that's about as electron was working perfectly fine before.

Comment: As Rob has commented above, you would be better to raise this as a separate question to get a quicker response from someone who is familiar with this issue. The json is valid so it must be something to do with the electron setup. I would advise making sure it's installed globally as it appears that it's not available when you try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have many coma mistakes.
Use this page to correct your JSON :
https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Here is your JSON corrected :

```
{
  "name": "password-generator",
  "productName": "Password Generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Password generator desktop app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build-installer": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "password-generator"
  },
  "win": {
    "target": ["nsis"],
    "icon": "/icon.png"
  },
  "nsis": {
    "installerIcon": "/icon.png",
    "uninstallerIcon": "/icon.png",
    "uninstallDisplayName": "Password Generator",
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  },
  "author": "JipBit",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^22.7.0"
  }
}
```